# Issues with upgrading

Tags: 7, upgrading

I am trying to upgrade from Drupal 6.28 to Drupal 7.22. By following the steps that were available on Drupal community doc, I succeeded in upgrading it to Drupal 7 successfully. I upgraded core, migrated CCK fields as well, but there are issues with the Views module: Various fields are not working. It is showing an error for a missing or broken handler.

The issue is that Drupal 6 had an embedded video field which was not included in Drupal 7. In Drupal 6, the widget type was embedded video, while in Drupal 7 the widget that we get by embedded media selector is media file selector.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you followed all the steps, I assume you have (or can get) a working copy of original 6.x page.

The question is - are your *nodes* OK?

- If they work properly, it means you have data in good enough state. Delete views that include problematic fields and recreate them from the ground. Optionally export them, remove fields that cause problems from exported file, delete from server, import and add fields. That's the easy case
- Sadly, if there was changes in the fields you were using in the very nodes, that renders nodes unusable, it will be worse. You will need to export data from 6.x site to some more or less universal format, like csv or xml, and import it anew to 7.x

  - Delete migrated data and it's content type
  - Create new content type with new-style fields, that maps 1:1 to old node structure. If possible, keep names
  - Export node data, using [Node Export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export), [Views data export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) or similar tool
  - Secure all the files referenced by nodes
  - If needed, manually upload secured files to new version; see next step
  - Import nodes using tool like [Node Export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) or [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) - it may be required for files to be already uploaded, read the manual of your importing tool