# Upgrade from D6 cause unability to edit existing node

Tags: entities, upgrading

After upgrading my Drupal website from D6 to D7, I regularly get this error message that prevents me from being able to edit existing nodes:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>
> PDOException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer
>   value: '' for column 'field_galerie_image_vdl_width' at row 1: INSERT
>   INTO {field_data_field_galerie_image_vdl} (entity_type, entity_id,
>   revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_galerie_image_vdl_fid,
>   field_galerie_image_vdl_alt, field_galerie_image_vdl_title,
>   field_galerie_image_vdl_width, field_galerie_image_vdl_height) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_10), (:db_insert_placeholder_11,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_14, :db_insert_placeholder_15,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_16, :db_insert_placeholder_17,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_18, :db_insert_placeholder_19,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_20, :db_insert_placeholder_21),
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_22, :db_insert_placeholder_23,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_24, :db_insert_placeholder_25,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_26, :db_insert_placeholder_27,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_28, :db_insert_placeholder_29,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_30, :db_insert_placeholder_31,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_32), (:db_insert_placeholder_33,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_34, :db_insert_placeholder_35,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_36, :db_insert_placeholder_37,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_38, :db_insert_placeholder_39,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_40, :db_insert_placeholder_41,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_42, :db_insert_placeholder_43); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 97
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 98 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] =>
>   contenu_sortie_action [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 251
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => [:db_insert_placeholder_8] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => [:db_insert_placeholder_10] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => 97
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_13] => 98 [:db_insert_placeholder_14] =>
>   contenu_sortie_action [:db_insert_placeholder_15] => 1
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_16] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_17] => 252
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_18] => [:db_insert_placeholder_19] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_20] => [:db_insert_placeholder_21] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_22] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_23] => 97
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_24] => 98 [:db_insert_placeholder_25] =>
>   contenu_sortie_action [:db_insert_placeholder_26] => 2
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_27] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_28] => 253
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_29] => [:db_insert_placeholder_30] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_31] => [:db_insert_placeholder_32] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_33] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_34] => 97
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_35] => 98 [:db_insert_placeholder_36] =>
>   contenu_sortie_action [:db_insert_placeholder_37] => 3
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_38] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_39] => 254
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_40] => [:db_insert_placeholder_41] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_42] => [:db_insert_placeholder_43] => ) dans
>   field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (ligne 451 dans
>   /var/www/drupal7/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).

What can I do to fix this?

I also can't finalise my upgrade due to missing a widget in field type too - could these problems be linked?

Comment: Looks like I answered your issue here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74715/issues-with-upgrading-drupal-6-to-drupal-7/74794#74794
Not the exact same question, but close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was changes in the fields you were using in the very nodes, that renders nodes unusable, you will need to export data from 6.x site to some more or less universal format, like csv or xml, and import it anew to 7.x

- Delete migrated data and it's content type
- Create new content type with new-style fields, that maps 1:1 to old node structure. If possible, keep names
- Export node data from original site (recreated from backup if needed), using [Node Export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export), [Views data export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) or similar tool
- Secure all the files referenced by nodes
- If needed, manually upload secured files to new version; see next step
- Import nodes using tool like [Node Export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) or [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) - it may be required for files to be already uploaded, read the manual of your importing tool

Comment: so upgrading content at the same time upgrading drupal core isn't the right way ? i've tried the migrate module that it's complete and do the job correctly

Comment: It's theoretical right way that fails way to often to treat is as universal and reliable. Most content types in my experience translates pretty OK, but I'm yet to see a page that will upgrade major version without any problems and manual work.

Comment: so to verify if i understand, i can check content type that work properly and keep them in this state.For those that doesn't work (break on edit for example) i need to delete them, recreate the content type and then migrate the content "by hand", right ?

Comment: @webmasterpf That's the best way I found so far.

Comment: what do you think about changing the widget type of a custom field before doing the upgrade ? like changing the widget to "text field" instead of "select list" for a text field type, idem for a file field type, set the widget on "upload file" instead of "image";then, field migration would be easier ?

Comment: @webmasterpf widget type is not a part of data (just a way to edit it), so changing it should not affect data at all. However, if you know widget will not exist after upgrade, changing it to one that will exist might make after-upgrade work easier. But it should be possible to change widget to existing one after upgrade too, anyway, so it hardly is an essential thing to do.

Comment: this issue seem to target nodes that contains csutom fields, because "single nodes" can be edited as usual..

Comment: Yea, but problem is not with widget. It's with the field type. And you cannot change type of a field, only the way it is edited.

Comment: ok i did test and delete nodes then import them via migrate d2d work..i just need to set tags (terms) with vbo..

Comment: Glad it helped, sorry for tags.

Comment: your way seem to be good, but actually i need to fix my import vi amigrate because nodes are imported whithout files or terms..i post another question for that